# omnet++ Error displaying random nodes

Tags: omnet++

Hii I generte X number of nodes to be spread uniformally in a certain network radius around a server as below in the .NED files

```
network myNetwork
        {
           parameters: 
               double netR @unit(m) = default(1040.5m);
               volatile double rndR = uniform(0,1);
                volatile double rndTheta = uniform(0,1);

        submodules:
            server: Server{
                    netR = netR;
             }
            host[numHosts]: Host {
                    r= netR*(sqrt(rndR)); 
                theta=2*3.14*rndTheta;
        }
}
simple Host
{
    parameters:
         double r @unit(m);
        double theta;
        double x @unit(m)= r*cos(theta);   // the x coordinate of the host
        double y @unit(m) = r*sin(theta);   // the y coordinate of the host
        @display("p=$x,$y");
}
```

However as the number of nodes increase the hosts are plotted incorrectly on the simulator. For example if numHosts = 1400, one node is plotted out of range as in the attached image
[[image: host(1328)is plotted incorrectly[1]]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you check whether the node is just plotted apart or whether the coordinates are incorrect as well.

Comment: @JulianHeinovski The node is plotted apart and the x, y coordinates are rounded down.  I used the below code & results shown    EV << "x: " <<x <<endl;
  EV << "y: " <<y <<endl;
        EV << "getX: " << getDisplayString().getTagArg("p", 0) <<endl;
        EV << "getY: " << getDisplayString().getTagArg("p", 1) <<endl;          
        INFO (Host) LoRa.host[1328]: LoRa.host[1328]: x: -1.48064
         INFO (Host)LoRa.host[1328]: LoRa.host[1328]: y: 219.664
         INFO (Host)LoRa.host[1328]: LoRa.host[1328]: getX: -1
         INFO (Host)LoRa.host[1328]: LoRa.host[1328]: getY: 219

Comment: @JerzyD. Why is that node plotted incorrectly? although it was suppose to be placed within a certain region?

Comment: @JulianHeinovski please note that this rounding down also happens with the other nodes INFO (Host)LoRa.host[1327]: LoRa.host[1327]: x-251.281
INFO (Host)LoRa.host[1327]: LoRa.host[1327]: y-85.7959
INFO (Host)LoRa.host[1327]: LoRa.host[1327]: getX-251
INFO (Host)LoRa.host[1327]: LoRa.host[1327]: getY-85 however they r still displayed correctly